# Is there a way to use multiple arrays in an index and match function?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing, excel-formula

Really struggling with this. I have a range of cells I need to use the index and match formula to perform. How would I go about omitting a couple cells in the  middle of the range? Like AK:CH but omitting CA and CC? I cannot switch cell headers around:(

```
Cells(PoleRow, 3).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX($AK$12:$CH$12,1,MATCH(MIN($AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$" & PoleRow & "),$AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$" & PoleRow & ", 0)),"""")"
```

Comment: From what you write it's hard to tell what you are doing, but why not just write your own UDF and tailor it to do exactly what you require?

Comment: It will be better if you can explain using screenshots what you exactly want to do

Answer (score 0):

it is better to create UDF as commented by @Ron Rosenfeld, However if you only try to omit Column CA and CC then may try

```
Cells(PoleRow, 3).Formula = "=iferror(IF(MIN(AK" & PoleRow & ":BZ" & PoleRow & ")<CB" & PoleRow & ",IF(MIN(CD" & PoleRow & ":CH" & PoleRow & ")<MIN(AK" & PoleRow & ":BZ" & PoleRow & "),INDEX(CD12:CH12,1,MATCH(MIN(CD" & PoleRow & ":CH" & PoleRow & "),CD" & PoleRow & ":CH" & PoleRow & ",0)),INDEX(AK12:BZ12,1,MATCH(MIN(AK" & PoleRow & ":BZ" & PoleRow & "),AK" & PoleRow & ":BZ" & PoleRow & ",0))),CB" & PoleRow & "),"""")"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Here is my code for the user defined function. Public Function Add(number1 As Double)
Cells(PoleRow, 3).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX($AK$12:$CH$12,1,MATCH(MIN($AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$" & PoleRow & ", ""*Height""),$AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$" & PoleRow & ", 0)),"""")"
End Function

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i am new to UDF's sorry!